# Convert index into columns Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm having the following multi-index data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

item_id = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,7,7,7,7,7] 
target = [0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,2]
label = ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','a','a','a','b','c']

df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': item_id, 'target': target, 'label': label})
print(df)

group = df.groupby(['item_id', 'target']).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
print(group)
```

Here is the output:

`df`:

```
    item_id  target label
0         3       0     a
1         3       0     a
2         3       0     a
3         3       1     b
4         3       1     b
5         3       2     c
6         3       2     c
7         3       2     c
8         7       0     a
9         7       0     a
10        7       0     a
11        7       1     b
12        7       2     c
```

`group`:

```
                label
item_id target       
3       0       a,a,a
        1         b,b
        2       c,c,c
7       0       a,a,a
        1           b
        2           c
```

How could I convert target to columns as the following?

```
item_id     0       1       2
3       a,a,a     b,b   c,c,c
7       a,a,a       b       c
```

Comment: `group['label'].unstack()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **unstack()** to solve to problem

```
df_test = group['label'].unstack()
df_test.head()
```

Result:

```
target  0   1   2
item_id         
3   a,a,a   b,b c,c,c
7   a,a,a   b   c
```